# T SQL Query about grouping

Tags: t-sql

First image is my query output. Now I want to group the subject so that it become like the second image. Is it possible? Thanks for the help.

`select Subject, Grade,
   case when Grade >= 50 
    Then '1' 
    else '0' 
    end as Pass,
case when Grade < 50 
    Then '1' 
    else '0' 
    end as Fail
from Grade_report`

OUTPUT:

[image]

what I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specification is not very exact; what number do you expect in the grade on the merged record, and should it just write 1 or 0 or aggregate the sum of the pass and fail columns?

The following will generate your output, it takes the `MAX` for the grade and `SUM` for pass/fail information:

```
WITH GradePassFail AS (
    SELECT 
        Subject, 
        Grade, 
        CASE WHEN Grade >= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Pass, 
        CASE WHEN Grade < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Fail 
    FROM Grade_report
)
SELECT Subject, MAX(Grade) AS Grade, SUM(Pass) AS Pass, SUM(Fail) AS Fail
FROM GradePassFail
GROUP BY Subject
```

Comment: is it possible to have only one select statement to generate the same output?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it is one statement... the common table expression defines a view that is then used, but in the end the query optimizer sees it all as one query. You could of course replace the CTE by a nested query, which would be equivalent.